# Compile AVD kernel for memory forensics with LiME

Tags: linux-kernel, android-emulator, kernel, clang, android-virtual-device

Hello this is my first time posting on stackoverflow so please forgive my naivety. I'm currently trying to compile a custom kernel with LKM enabled. The main problem is that all guides and tutorials are outdated. I can't find anything that would help or even guide in the right direction.
[**AVDs used for testing (Screenshot)**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cak38.png)
 **Cross-Compilers I've tried:**

**1.** google toolchain64 (deprecated 13 days ago)
**2.** Linario
**3.** UberTC
**4.** Clang
**5.** android-ndk-r21 toolchains

I've been working on this for 10 days now so any help would be really appreciated.

---

**Latest Attempt 1:**

Kernel: wahoo-android-msm-wahoo-4.4
toolchain:  gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-i686_aarch64-linux-gnu

Commands:

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=/path to tool chain/
export ARCH=arm64 
make clean
make mrproper
make wahoo_defconfig
make menuconfig (to enable LKM)
make -j12
```

> ***ERROR:*** 
>
>   fails to build an image, gives no error

---

**Latest Attempt 2:**

Kernel: git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/goldfish/ -b android-goldfish-4.9-dev
toolchain:  gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-i686_aarch64-linux-gnu

Commands:

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=/path to tool chain/
export ARCH=arm64
make clean
make mrproper
make goldfish_defconfig
make menuconfig (to enable LKM)
make -j12
```

> ***ERROR:*** 
>
>   qemu: linux kernel too old to load a ram disk

---

**EDIT:**

**Latest Attempt 3:**

Kernel: git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common -b cuttlefish-4.4
toolchain:  gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-i686_aarch64-linux-gnu

Commands:

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=/path to tool chain/
export ARCH=arm64
make clean
make mrproper
make cuttlefish_defconfig
make menuconfig (to enable LKM)
make -j12
```

> ***ERROR:*** 
>
>   duke@duke:~$ emulator -avd Nexus5X2 -kernel 
> /home/duke/Downloads/cuttlefish/arch/arm64/boot/Image
>   emulator: WARNING: encryption is off
>   emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:102: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037
>   queryCoreProfileSupport: swap interval not found
>   failed to create drawable
>   failed to create drawable
>   failed to create drawable
>   failed to create drawable
>   failed to create drawable
>   failed to create drawable
>   failed to create drawable
>   failed to create drawable
>   qemu: linux kernel too old to load a ram disk

---

**EDIT 2:**

**Latest Attempts 4 / 5:**

Kernels:
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common -b cuttlefish-4.4
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/goldfish/ -b android-goldfish-4.9-dev

toolchain: android-ndk-r21

Commands:

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/linux- x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android-
export ARCH=x86_64
make clean
make mrproper
make x86_64_defconfig
make menuconfig (to enable LKM)
make -j12
emulator -avd MANY -kernel x86/boot/bzImage †
emulator -avd MANY -kernel x86/boot/bzImage -verbose ††
emulator -avd MANY -kernel x86/boot/bzImage -no-snapshot-load -ranchu †††
```

> ***ERROR:*** †
>   No error, AVD FAILS TO BOOT. I've waited 30 min
>
> ***ERROR:*** ††
>   emulator: No acpi ini file provided, using default
>
> ***ERROR:*** †††
>   No error, AVD FAILS TO BOOT. I've waited 30 min

Comment: "The main problem is that all guides and tutorials are outdated" - Are you sure that they outdated? Have you tried to use them?

Comment: Yes I have tried almost all of them but to no avail.

Comment: Please, add your attempts to the question post, and show the error message you got. On Stack Overflow we don't write *guides*, and questions about them are **off-topic**. But we could help you with a problems you faced with when following some (existed) guide.

Comment: I've updated the original question. Kindly if you could have a look. Thanks.